# java.lang.RuntimeException: Expecting menu, got ScrollView

Tags: android, screen, scrollview, runtimeexception

I have created an android application which runs perfectly in Samsung galaxy ace device.
But when I run the same on HTC Desire V, it is giving FATAL EXCEPTION.
Note: Samsung device is 3.5 inch screen device while HTC is 4 inch device.
The error showing in logcat is as below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Expecting menu, got ScrollView
at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:128)
at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:95)
at com.pixel.hp.activity.HandpumpActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(HandpumpActivity.java:1476)
at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2508)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:407)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:762)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:3083)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is it because of change in screen size or something else?
Any idea on this would be very helpful.

I am getting error in below method (2nd line is HandpumpActivity.java:1476) :

```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_handpump, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is in HandpumpActivity.java:1476 line of your code?

Comment: what you have created in your application. is it about menus.? There might be something wrong with the size or the orientation of the panels or whatever you have used. So it would be better to post some relavent code.

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah: please check my edited question. There i have mentioned line:1476

Comment: Do you have more than one `/res/menu` folder (for different languages for e.g.)?

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah: No, I have only one Menu folder under res..

Comment: Please post your activity_handpump as it seems you have fixed attributes that are outside the bounds of the screen.

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah: activity_handpump.xml is very big. When i post it, I am getting error like Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 35240

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your `activity_handpump.xml` only contains `<menu>`, `<item>` or `<group>` elements. `<ScrollView>` should not be in `activity_handpump.xml` as per the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml).

The only explanation on how it is working on Galaxy Ace that I could think of is that you are having different Layouts for menus loaded for different screen sizes (Ace is mdpi while Desire is hdpi)

Comment: thanks for the reply. this may help me in some context. Will go through the link.

Comment: Apparently if you name a class as 'Menu' and rename it, all xml files that contains <'menu'> would rename it to the new name you refactored it to.